# Android Integration test reading a bitmap from Uri

Tags: android, testing, integration-testing

I've a MVP architecture and in one Presenter I want to test a method to retrieve a `Bitmap` from a `Uri` internal to the phone

the method is along those lines

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, Uri uri) {
...
try {
    final InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
    input.close();
    }
...
}
```

Now I'm not really familiar with the new Android Test Suite, and I don't want to use (if possible) external libraries like Robolectric, so I am a bit at loss on how to proceed...

My thoughts were to go for an `instrumentation test` since I depend on the Android component `Context`

```
@Test
public void getScreenshot() {
    final Uri uriBitmap = Uri.parse("testFile.jpg");
    final Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

    final Bitmap retrieved = presenter.getBitmap(context, uriBitmap);
    assertEquals(retrieved, preInjectedTestFile.jpg)
}
```

but then I am not sure how can I "inject" a testFile.jpg in the file system for the duration of the test...
Moreover I'm not sure if the Context I am using is the same one of the hosting app or a test one, which would be better not to mess around with the "official" app memory

Comment: `a method to retrieve a Bitmap from memory

the method is along those lines`.  There is nothing in that code that retrieves anything from memory.

Comment: sorry I meant "a method to retrieve a bitmap from an input stream obtained from a URI"